# How to sort an object by it's child object fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

How could I sort products by `GroupModel.PeerOrder` but only if `GroupModel.ParentGroupId` matches some id?

My C# models:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public List<GroupModel> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class GroupModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public int ParentGroupId { get; set; }
    public int PeerOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to filter matching "*GroupModel.ParentGroupId*" values and then apply [Nested Sort Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html) to sort results by "*GroupModel.PeerOrder*".

As per documentation:

**Nested Query**: Nested query allows to query nested objects / docs (see nested mapping). The query is executed against the nested objects / docs as if they were indexed as separate docs (they are, internally) and resulting in the root parent doc (or parent nested mapping). Here is a sample mapping:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "obj1" : {
                    "type" : "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "obj1",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"obj1.name" : "blue"} },
                    { "range" : {"obj1.count" : {"gt" : 5}} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Nested Sort Query**: It is possible to sort by the value of a nested field, even though the value exists in a separate nested document.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": { 
      "path": "comments",
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "comments.date": {
            "gte": "2014-10-01",
            "lt":  "2014-11-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "comments.stars": { 
      "order": "asc",   
      "mode":  "min",   
      "nested_filter": { 
        "range": {
          "comments.date": {
            "gte": "2014-10-01",
            "lt":  "2014-11-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up with (With the help from @ydrall - thank you very much! :>):

**The query part (for us is works just fine without this first part):**

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
        "must": [                
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "groups", 
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [ 
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "groups.parentGroupId": 3
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
    ]
  }
}
```

**The sorting part of the query:**

```
"sort": [
{
    "groups.peerOrder": { 
      "order": "asc",
        "nested_path": "groups",   
      "nested_filter": { 
        "match": {
          "groups.parentGroupId": 3 
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

**Index mappings:**

```
 "mappings": {
    "productmodel": {
      "properties": {
          "groups": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "parentGroupId": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "peerOrder": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```